# Exchanging Manuscripts with Beta Readers

Tags: beta-readers

I am a newbie. Is there a particular group or section or length on the Stack Exchange website? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is not beta reader group on the Stack Exchange network. There are many beta reader groups on Goodreads, Reddit, Facebook and elsewhere. Look here: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22how+to+find+beta+readers%22

Comment: [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/168) (requires 20 reputation points across SE) is the only place on SE where such requests are allowed. However, considering how inactive our chat is, you're unlikely to get a response. See [Where is a good place to find beta readers?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/1529/34330) for places outside SE.

Comment: @Laurel, your comment seems to be the perfect response to this question. Providing this as an answer seems more constructive than the attempt to close the question as unclear. And, It will benefit future users.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is a good place to find beta readers?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/1529/where-is-a-good-place-to-find-beta-readers)

Comment: Yes, it answers my question clearly. I think all of you for your responses. I will follow the links provided. Have a happy new year to all of you!